# How can I easily share clippings across platforms and networks?

Tags: network

I have to use a Windows PC at work, but I often bring my MacBook Air so I can get work done that is hard or inefficient to perform on Windows.  I am not allowed to connect my Mac to the corporate network, so when I do something on the Mac and want to copy from the Mac and paste into an app on the Windows laptop, there's no easy way.  No network clipboard manager <del>I've ever seen</del> I had seen at the time I wrote this question works when your two machines are not on the same network.  (Obviously both machines are connected to the internet, however.)

Using Dropbox or (worse yet) e-mail or (worst of all) a flash drive is too painful.  I want a simple and ***almost effortless*** way of transferring data or text between machines—something so easy *and transparent* that I don't have to think about the process, but can instead focus on whatever work I'm doing and not lose that focus.

How can I achieve this?

Some sort of Bluetooth data transfer *might* be allowed, as long as there's no TCP/IP connection to the Mac over Bluetooth, or something like that.  But I'm guessing the solution will more likely involve both machines communicating in some fashion over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) (free, $5/month or $45/year for premium)

> The Evernote family of products help you remember and act upon ideas, projects and experiences across all the computers, phones and tablets you use.

[Simplenote](http://simplenote.com/) (free)

> An easy way to keep notes, lists, ideas, and more...Keep notes on the web, your mobile device, and your computer.

Comment: Okay, that's an idea I hadn't thought of, but how is this better than sending an e-mail or saving a draft message in G-mail?  I have to use an application on each end to send and retrieve the clipping, instead of having some way of passing from clipboard to clipboard?  Remember I'm looking for something that is *almost effortless*.  Anyway, thanks for the idea, maybe I'll fall back on that if nothing else works.

Comment: @iconoclast True. Neither are completely effortless. But when you're talking cross-platform, cross-computer, something like either of these services is going to be the best you can do unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudclip](http://www.getcloudclip.com/) is the only application I've found that communicates over the internet rather than a local area network.

It is crashing for me on Windows, and on OS X it has the disadvantage of being a visibly open application (it appears in your Command-Tab menu, and your Dock) which makes no UI sense (it should unobtrusively sit in the menubar until you need to change preferences or whatever), but it appears to be the only game in town given the networking constraints I am (and presumably many others are) under.  If they solve the crashing problem this may be a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, how about a VNC connection? Use a client that supports the clipboards of both systems.

Also, how about turning on file sharing on your mac and paste your clippings into a RTF that is in your public or similar folder?

Comment: The networking to make that work may be very difficult given the circumstances. Remember: I don't have the two computers on the same network, and I *can't* have them on the same network, so there has to be a computer "out there" on the internet somewhere that they can both connect to via an outbound connection, which will coordinate things.  And it still wouldn't make things anywhere close to being effortless.  But thanks for the suggestion anyway!